# SQL Server: extremely slow table on a simple select

Tags: sql-server, azure, query-optimization

I am dealing with a SQL Server on Azure, and I found a rare case where queries over a single table are really slow, over 10 - 12 seconds for a table that has about thousand rows, and while similar tables respond in less that 1 second.

Table definition (script create) is:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Content] 
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Content_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CultureCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Subtitle] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    ... 14 more [nvarchar](max) FIELDS...
    [NotesPlainText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_dbo.Content] 
         PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                     WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                           IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                           ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
)
```

(the columns `Content_ID`, `CultureCode` and `Version` seem to be a unique combination, even is not set in the table as that. `[ID]` is just used as row identifier)

Aside of 17 columns all `nvarchar(max)`, nothing else weird.

As I said, no uniques defined, no index ...

So I tune up as

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Content_optimized]
(
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Content_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CultureCode] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [Version] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Timestamp] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [Title] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,
    [Subtitle] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    ... 14 more [nvarchar](max) FIELDS...
    [NotesPlainText] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)

CREATE INDEX IDX_dbo_Content_optimized__Content_ID 
       ON [dbo].[Content_optimized]([Content_ID])
CREATE INDEX IDX_dbo_Content_optimized__CultureCode 
       ON [dbo].[Content_optimized]([CultureCode])
CREATE INDEX IDX_dbo_Content_optimized__Version 
       ON [dbo].[Content_optimized]([Version])
CREATE INDEX IDX_dbo_Content_optimized__UserID 
       ON [dbo].[Content_optimized]([UserID])

ALTER INDEX ALL ON [dbo].[Content_optimized] REBUILD WITH (FILLFACTOR=90, ONLINE=ON)
```

and here where things get weird, I am not saving even a single second of execution.

Indeed code like this:

```
select * 
from [Content]  
where Content_ID <> 1049 
order by Content_ID, Version

select * 
from [Content_optimized]  
where Content_ID <> 1049 
order by Content_ID, Version
```

gives a 53% and 47% on the execution plan (just 11% faster because of the INDEXes)

Sure I am relative new to SQL optimisation, so there is something I am not seeing here that may be obvious, but I am right now lost on it.

Any help?

Comment: It could just be the amount of data in those nvarchar(max) columns. Right click the table>-Properties>-Storage to compare the data space used by the table compared to the faster accessed tables.

Comment: can you share execution plan here :https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/.

Comment: Why is everything varchar(max)? From the names on the columns I doubt you need to allow that much data. Surely the values can be constrained to less than 8,000 characters for most of those columns?

Comment: @TheGameiswar Why are you asking for the OP to share content on an external site? This is the *opposite* of what should be encouraged on StackOverflow.

Comment: @DavidMakogon:i see this was done many times and it is not a bad practice..you can see the results using this search item :site:dba.stackexchange.com brentozar.com/pastetheplan

Comment: Is this SQL on a VM or SQL Azure?

Comment: @BrianAtkins -> yes, this is "Esparta", sorry, Azure ...

Comment: @cloudsafe -> so, no Properties->storage :-((

Comment: @TheGameiswar : execution plan : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=B1GujafUg
(I have replace in the XML 14 fields with a filed called 14fields, sorry, I can not publish the names)

Comment: even table size should be "not big"

I just made a :
**select sum(len(isnull([field01],0)) + ... + sum(len(isnull([field17],0))** 
for all NVARCHAR(max) fields, and the result is 1040539 (and it got executed in no time :-)

Comment: something else I may provide?

Comment: @pGmd If having problems use this: exec sp_spaceused [TableName]

Comment: @cloudsafe, I run the sp, with Content, and with headers (similar table, no nvarchar(max) fields, and double lines)

Comment: exec sp_spaceused 'Headers'

Comment: exec sp_spaceused 'Contents'

Comment: name------rows---reserved---data-----index_size---unused

Comment: Content---967----5320KB-----2752KB---656KB--------1912KB

Comment: Headers---1760---1064KB-----208KB----248KB--------608KB

Comment: (and sorry for the several comments, but I do not know other way to show diferent lines)

Comment: It shows that, per row, Content has 24 times as much data as Headers. I would expect queries on Contents to be returned slower.

Comment: @cloudsafe - yes, I understand that this will be a slower query, but still, a simple query over a table with indexes with 1000 rows, shouldn't take 10-12 seconds, it has just 3mb.
What about a query on a table, with even just a bunch of integers over a millions lines?, should that take like three weeks ?

Comment: @pGmd Try the query just returning the [ID] column, then gradually add more columns while checking the time it takes. It should demonstrate that the time it takes is proportional to the amount of data.

Comment: @cloudsafe, really, can't relate, today select * and select [ID] took both about 2 seconds, (first one same as before took about 10-12 seconds). Execution plan of both queries together at 50% each ... [got confused]

Comment: @pGrnd If it was a local SQL Server it would take approximately the same time, but with Azure you are transferring large quantities of data over the internet. It will depend on your connection. Try to write queries to reduce the amount of data being returned.